# Need Java print statement after loop

Tags: java

I am working on the current program and I need the * print statement to print all at once at the end. However, it keeps printing after each number is entered. I am new to java and any assistance would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class barPrint
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int counter = 0;
        int value = 0;

        // counter loop for 5 inputs
        for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++){
            System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
            value = input.nextInt();

            while(value < 1 || value > 30){
                System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
                value = input.nextInt();
            }
            // print the asterisks based on value
            for (int i = 0; i < value; i++){
                System.out.print("*");

                }
                System.out.println();
        }
        System.exit (0);
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 25
*************************
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 22
**********************
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 1
*
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 12
************
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 10
**********

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

Expected Output:

```
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 25
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 22
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 1
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 12
Input an integer between 1 and 30: 10


*************************
**********************
*
************
**********

Process finished with exit code 0.
```

Comment: Where did you put the code that prints the `*`'s? _That's_ where it's going to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array to store to your various counts, here is one such solution -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  // values holds room for 5 inputs
  int[] values = new int[5];

  for (int counter = 0; counter < values.length; counter++) {
    System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
    System.out.flush();
    int value = input.nextInt(); // <-- declare value here.

    while (value < 1 || value > 30) {
      System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
      System.out.flush();
      value = input.nextInt();
    }
    values[counter] = value; // <-- store it in the values array.
  }
  // Use the for each operator to iterate over the value(s)...
  for (int value : values) {
    // print the asterisks based on value
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.flush();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Another approach would be to store your output into a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), like so -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) {
    System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
    System.out.flush();
    int value = input.nextInt();

    while (value < 1 || value > 30) {
      System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
      System.out.flush();
      value = input.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
      sb.append("*");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
  }
  System.out.println(sb.toString());
  System.out.flush();
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This worked the best and I see why it has to be an array as 
user3256147 stated. The value gets lost at the end of each line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Move the for loop with the * print to right before the exit

Comment: How so? He wants to know where to put the print right?

Comment: Well it is an answer, I understand its short but some questions only need a short answer

Comment: As per the help answers should never be comments. Citing the section where it says "when shouldn't I comment" http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, like the above answer stated, place the following `for` loop outside of the other loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < value; i++){
     System.out.print("*");
}
```

rather than inside, as have you done.

Secondly, I do not see the point of having this:

```
System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
value = input.nextInt();

while(value < 1 || value > 30){
       System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
       value = input.nextInt();
}
```

Taking your input twice seems to be redundant. Delete the first two statements, and instead use `do while`:

```
do{
       System.out.print("Input an integer between 1 and 30: ");
       value = input.nextInt();
}while(value < 1 || value > 30);
```

I believe you'll still get a logical error, however (i'm not sure what your program intends to do). You seem to want to print the total number of asterixis, so you'd either have to add the value to itself each time you take input, or you'll have to use a stringbuilder to append it within the loop.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. However, he does not need the first two statements, and instead of them, the loop can be changed into a `do - while` one. It's cleaner like that, in my opinion.

Comment: The program intends to take an integer input between 1 and 30 and output that number as asterisks. For example, 7 is *******. I wanted to use arrays as I am familiar with C programming, but we have not covered them yet in class. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Do you want to print the total asterixis (ie: add all the inputs and print that many on one line at once) or do you want to print them line by line as per your input (ie: if you input `5`, `6`, `7` and `8`, it will print 5 asterixis, go to the next line, print 6 more, go to the next line, print 7 more, and go to the next line and finally print 8 more)? It would help if you could update your question with how your intended output would look (unless you've already solved your problem of course).

Comment: Elliot's answer will produce the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print all the stars continuously when you have variable as integer.
U need to have arrays ..
Because if at all u need to print all the * at the end,you need to have track of the count of stars in each line...
If u use integer, by the time you enter the next line count, you will lose the previous line count...

Algorithm for your ques is:

1.declare an array

2.get the total no of lines to be displayed

3.get the count of total no of stars in each line ( and store this in array )

4.display the stars based on the count in this array.